# How to take bytestring and get back an accented character in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I have a string originating from an email. I'm not sure of the string's original encoding, however in an email client it shows up like so:

```
'Somebody LastNáme'
```

I assumed that it was a utf-8 encoding. When I decode it from utf-8,...

```
'Somebody LastNáme'.decode('utf-8')
```

... I get the following unicode string in a python shell:

```
 u'Somebody LastN\xe1me'
```

I also tried a latin-1 encoding, after browsing the docs on unicode, and seeing an acute accent encoded as latin-1. Decoding as that, it shows up the same way, i.e. with the byte not able to be represented as ascii showing up instead as `\xe1`.

I would like to know **1)** if it is possible to get python to show me accented characters when I am looking at non-ascii strings in a terminal (instead of escaped), and **2)** whether (or how I can make sure that) the string will be rendered properly in a browser when I subsequently make use of it.

Comment: You're looking at the *representation* of the string. `print` the string (or write it to a file, etc.), and it will be fine. Compare `print repr(s)` vs. `print s`. The interactive interpreter defaults to showing you the representation if you just enter an expression without printing it.

Comment: Ahhh, such a small thing. That answers both my questions.